# How to change Visual Studio 2017 Windows build to Linux build

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

So, I have a project being built and test on Windows platform, since Visual Studio 2017 works and run program most comfortable for me in Windows. Now, that I have completed debug most part of the code, I'll have to change my platform built target to Linux.

I used an external project (lib) to help with the internet control, which it's built target is also Windows.
Both the project are written with under C++17 standards so cross-platform should work fine.

Following the instruction on Microsoft website, I had successfully built a test project on my remote Linux server.

However, all the tutorials seem to ask people to start up a new "Linux Project", in which I did for the test project. The question is, since I already have a project/solution created and the build target is Windows platform, is there a way to switch the build to Linux Remote Build?

I've tried opening project settings, but the "target build" option is always Windows 10 and is not changeable.